# React call JSON data with string

Tags: reactjs

```
import AsukaData from './info/AsukaData.json'
import JinData from './info/JinData.json'

~~~~

const CharArray = [
  'Jin', 'Asuka'
]
{CharArray.map((element,index)=>(
          <Route path={`/${element}`}><CharPage Data={`${element}Data`}/></Route>
     ))}
```

I want to call JSON data(JinData, AsukaData) with string, but don't know how to do..

Data={`${element}Data`} is recognized as string. And I want it to be json that is imported above.

Comment: Your question not clear, kindly update it with explaining what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Using the backticks indicates string interpolations/templates.

```
Data={`${element}Data`}
```

This takes the string value from the array, and injects and returns a new string value passed to the `Data` prop.

## Solution

If you simply want to map the imported JSON objects then I suggest placing them in the array. Use an object to provide the path key, and the JSON data payload.

```
import AsukaData from './info/AsukaData.json'
import JinData from './info/JinData.json'

...
const charArray = [
  { path: 'Jin', data: JinData },
  { path: 'Asuka', data: AsukaData }
];

{charArray.map(({ path, data }) => (
  <Route key={path} path={`/${path}`}>
    <CharPage Data={data} />
  </Route>
))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an object instead of array to map data with keys

```
const DataMap = {
  'Jin': JinData, 
  'Asuka': AsukaData
}
{Object.keys(DataMap).map((element,index)=>(
     <Route path={`/${element}`}><CharPage Data={DataMap[element]}/></Route>
))}
```